# changing template for one of product media isn't working

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I am presenting one product media section different from other. And i tried changing the template.

On catalog.xml file i can see this section is responsible for media

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
         <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />
     </block>
     <!--/ other block section -->
</block>
```

And to overwrite it's template, in my `local.xml` file

```
<layout>
<!--/ Custom product -->
    <PRODUCT_776>
        <reference name="media">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/view/media-custom.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_776>
</layout>
```

But it's not overwriting this template.

More info:
 `<remove name="media"/>` under `<product_776/>` is removing the media section in product detail page. and i'm using rwd default theme as default fallback.

Comment: What happens when you set the same action not for `PRODUCT_776`, but for `catalog_product_view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the block name `product.info.media`, not the alias `media`. While alias works for the `remove` command, it does not always work for the `reference`.

Also, to exclude wrong files error or parsing priority you can add the XML via admin interface when edit product. See field "Custom Layout Update"

Comment: `While alias works for the remove command, it is not always works for the reference` i didn't know that, thank you